# Clearing search EditText always reloads content

Tags: bug, android-app

Clearing the search EditText will always reload questions even if no prior search has been made.

This is done either via keyboard or by clicking the X icon on the right of the EditText.

This behavior can be acceptable in a filtered result set (after a search) because it assumes the user is clearing the search keywords to get back to the original questions, but it is not normal in the initial unfiltered list.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Select a SE site from the navigation drawer.
2. Type anything in the search EditText (Do not hit the search button though).
3. Delete what you typed using backspace or the X icon.

Result: The questions will reload.

> [image: video proof]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (1634100298931)